# SQLite Add content from other table if limit has not been reached

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a quick question. I have two SQLite tables like the following:

`TableOne`

| id | rowone |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | rowone_content_a |
| 2 | rowone_content_ab |
| 3 | rowone_content_ac |
| 4 | rowone_content_bc |

`TableTwo`

| id | rowone | rowtwo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | rowone_content_a | a |
| 2 | rowone_content_ab | ab |
| 3 | rowone_content_ac | ac |
| 4 | rowone_content_bc | bc |

So I want a SQL that has the following behavior:

Search: `tent_a` (something that contains `tent_a` somewhere).

When I search for it, I want the following result:

| *rowname that doesn't matter* | *from table (not included in the output)* |
| --- | --- |
| a | `TableTwo` |
| ab | `TableTwo` |
| ac | `TableTwo` |
| rowone_content_a | `TableOne` |
| rowone_content_ab | `TableOne` |

Background is that I have a search that should first look in the first row of the second table and select the value of the second row if the value of the first row contains the text I am looking for, limited by 5. But if the data returned from table two is less than 5, the SQL should fill the empty fields with data found in table one.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` to get all the rows from the 2 tables that satisfy your conditions and then Use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` to return only the first 5 rows:

```
SELECT rowname
FROM (
  SELECT rowtwo rowname, 1 fromtable
  FROM TableTwo
  WHERE rowone LIKE '%tent\_a%' ESCAPE '\'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT rowone, 2
  FROM TableOne
  WHERE rowone LIKE '%tent\_a%' ESCAPE '\'
)  
ORDER BY fromtable, rowname LIMIT 5
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=8f52746440b2ce780ac36597f9136f0a).

Comment: Nice, good to know how to use it with order by and limit, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `union all`:

```
select rowone, 'tableone'
from tableone
where rowone like '%tent\_a%'
union all
select rowtwo, 'tabletwo'
from tabletwo
where rowone like '%tent\_a%'
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, what you wrote worked as expected.

Comment: How does this work as expected: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=04f610a81763b97c6efc9b27655d91ae?

Comment: I adjusted it a bit, so that it fits the real tables, worked fine.